# YouTube shorts parser

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, youtube

I saw youtube parser, which can get URLs of all videos on a channel, but I don't know how to make the same thing with youtube shorts. I've got problem with scrabetube - it only gets videos URLs from channel, not shorts. Any ideas? Code example:

```
import scrapetube
import pandas as pd

channelid = input("Type YouTube channel ID:\n")
list = []

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=["URL"])
videos = scrapetube.get_channel(channelid)

for video in videos:
    url1 = url+str(video['videoId'])
    print(url1)
    list.append(url1)

dataframe["URL"]=list
dataframe.to_json("MyURL.json")
print("Done!")
```

Should return "Done!" in console and create both .json and .xml files with all of the URLs in them.

Comment: https://github.com/dermasmid/scrapetube/pull/18/files, TLDR `get_channel(channelid, content_type="shorts")`